# Trying To Set Imageview With Background Operations

Tags: android

I am working with googlemap. I have implemented custom marker window, this window contains photo of the marker. I am taking the url of the photo as string and setting it into imageview with thread. However, the code is not syncronized with user. When I have clicked the marker, it shows the photo of the previous marker that I have clicked. When I did debug, I can see that true url values are coming from background but the setting image into imageview operation is becoming late. How can I solve this problem? I have tried picasso and glide but still same problem.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    this.Window = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_window, null);
    this.imageview = (ImageView) Window.findViewById(R.id.marker_photo);
    googleMap = map;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
                    createThread(imageview,URL).start();
                    mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                    return infoWindow;
                }
                return null;}
        });
}

private synchronized Thread createThread(final ImageView imageView, final String URL)
{
   Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           download_image(URL,imageView);
       }
   });
    return thread;
}

public void download_image(String url,ImageView imageview) {
    URL newurl = null;

    try {
        newurl = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the image on the ImageView off of the main UI thread.  If this code runs within an `Activity`, you can use the `runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable);` on the `imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` call to force it to occur on the UI thread.  If you're not within an Activity, you could use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) created with the main Looper, or the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial in getting images downloaded on a background thread to the UI thread. [Managing Multiple Threads](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html) It is addressing the management of multiple threads using an [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html/), but includes a good description of using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to get a Bitmap onto the UI thread.